Who is the difference?
Each line of the riddle has two answers.
The answers use the same letters except that one word is a single letter longer than the other.
Four words, One from each of the pairs share a theme.
The current riddle:
Ocean temptress needs weight for fishing
Many headed creature, rarely
Loving firebreather
Over-grilled Pan.

Who is the difference?

Ocean temptress needs weight for fishing

 Siren, sin(k)er

Many headed creature, rarely

 Hydra, hard(l)y

Loving firebreather

 Ador(i)ng, dragon

Over-grilled Pan.

 R(o)asty, satyr

Who is the difference?

 The extra letters spell "Klio", a fitting answer considering the mythology theme


*cough*
